# Ошибка org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Expected to read a START_MAP but instead have:

Tags: java, jenkins, selenide

При прогоне автотестов (java+gradle+selenide) на jenkins время от времени падают тесты на первом шаге (авторизация) с ошибкой org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Expected to read a START_MAP but instead have: END. Last 0 characters read:
Похоже, что после того, как 1 тест упал с этой ошибкой - следующие за ним автотесты тоже падают.
Ошибка воспроизводится 2-3 раза на 10 прогонов.
Локально не воспроизводится.

```
org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Expected to read a START_MAP but instead have: END. Last 0 characters read: 
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'ufr-unif2-development-qzq8c', ip: '10.233.68.68', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_242'
Driver info: driver.version: SelenideDriver
selenide.url: http://**********/ufr-unif-ui
selenide.baseUrl: http://localhost:8080
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.expect(JsonInput.java:290)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.beginObject(JsonInput.java:220)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.MapCoercer.lambda$apply$1(MapCoercer.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.lambda$null$6(JsonTypeCoercer.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.coerce(JsonTypeCoercer.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:87)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:609)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getTitle(RemoteWebDriver.java:281)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.BrowserHealthChecker.isBrowserStillOpen(BrowserHealthChecker.java:17)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.LazyDriver.getAndCheckWebDriver(LazyDriver.java:80)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.SelenideDriver.getAndCheckWebDriver(SelenideDriver.java:143)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:61)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.Navigator.open(Navigator.java:24)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.SelenideDriver.open(SelenideDriver.java:59)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open(Selenide.java:39)
    at ru.alfabank.unif.autotests.helpers.Auth.initializeDriver(Auth.java:39)
    at ru.alfabank.unif.autotests.helpers.Auth.makeAuth(Auth.java:30)
    at ru.alfabank.unif.autotests.steps.common.LoginSteps.openFrame(LoginSteps.java:32)
    at ✽.открыли фрейм "УКД" c ролью "Superuser" клиента с idsub "104589427" пин "XAMDQU"(/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/QA automation/Akita/build/resources/test/features/ui/remote_access_channels/remote_access_channelsCL2.feature:8)
```